# {"ERROR [08004] [ODBC Firebird Driver]unavailable database"}

Tags: odbc, firebird

I have an odbc connection, to connect to a WMS database (I believe they support ODBC only) and on connection open gets the exception {"ERROR [08004] [ODBC Firebird Driver]unavailable database"}. The WMS Server & Client components are installed on the machine where my code also runs. Connection string below

```
"DRIVER=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver; UID=SYSADMIN; PWD=MASTERKEY; DBNAME=C:\Sample\Db.FDB;"
```

I am clueless on how to proceed. Some of the already seen answers says, only one application can access the db at a time or so. In that case how I find who else trying to access this db and stop?

Comment: Have you tried changing `DBNAME` to `localhost:C:\Sample\Db.FDB`? If that doesn't work, then your WMS might be using Firebird Embedded, which - depending on the Firebird version - locks the database file for exclusive access. BTW: I suggest you contact the support of your WMS supplier for this information. Also note that if they actually use Firebird, then you don't need to use ODBC, you can also use any of the other drivers for Firebird.

Comment: On prefixing DBNAME with 'localhost:', the error is different. {"ERROR [08004] [ODBC Firebird Driver]Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login."}. How can I proceed further? What exactly should I ask for if contact WMS?

Comment: That is because `SYSADMIN` either doesn't exist on your server, or you're using the wrong password. You might mean `SYSDBA` instead (which is the normal 'super user' account of Firebird). As to contacting support, your question sounds like you're trying to get free support from us, instead of contacting your supplier for information. Contact them first.

Comment: Thanks Mark. SYSDBA also giving same error as above. The history is our client has a product to work with various databases, WMS being one of them. The product is getting now converted to C# and I am getting the above issue. I shall contact our client with your suggestions and input for them to contact WMS support may be. I don't think I was trying to get free support, but may be had very little or no knowledge around this area to put my question right, which was misinterpreted then :)

Comment: "masterkey" should be in low letters not caps, read some firebird FAQ or manual. That, providing no one changed that "out of the box" default SYSDBA's password. But if on your system SYSDBA's password was customized, then you would have to ask your software support that they give you working login/password for connecting to the database

Comment: "getting now converted to C#" - then maybe it would make sense to drop old ODBC drivers and instead move to either Firebird .Net Provider or to http://IBProvider.com

Comment: UserName was same as in the connectionstring I gave, but password they gave wrongly, in uppercase. Lowercase password with SYSADMIN worked. @Arioch'The, any idea if the .net provider for Firebird has a GetSchema method to retrieve schema info of Tables, Columns, Primary Keys and ForeignKeys? Or should I run some db queries to get that? ODBC does not have PK & FK Schema info from GetSchema method like OleDb. Knowing this info help me to decide if I should try for FireBird .Net. Is there any other provider for firebird that helps get all the above schema info?

Comment: I don't work with C# so I can't tell technical details. I think you give a try to both providers I mentioned above, free and commercial, including how scarce/vast is documentation/examples and fast/slow they are on user support. Also, you might reconstruct schema manually by querying Firebird system tables, though I can relate why you'd prefer provider itself doing that. You may try to dig further starting with http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/documentation/firebird_adonet_p3_ddl_odbc_metadata.html

Comment: Using FirebirdClient helps get all the required schema info, so using that.